# Shiny output works only if ui.R was closed as last file

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have really strange behavior of my shiny tool.

One of datatable outputs doesn't appear on the page, but if I re-open and close ui.R file without any changes and then reload the page, it appears without any problems.

In ui.R here is what I have to this data table output:

```
fluidRow(column(width = 12,box(width =NULL,dataTableOutput("df"))))
```

And in server.R:

```
GetDB=eventReactive(input$updatetable, {
  dbibase<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "user", password = "mypas",dbname = "dbname", host="host")
dbGetQuery(dbibase,"set names utf8")
gettable<-data.table(dbGetQuery(dbibase, "Select * FROM PIPELINE;"))
dbDisconnect(dbibase)
gettable
}, ignoreNULL=FALSE)

output$df<-DT:: renderDataTable({DT:: datatable(GetDB(),extensions = 'FixedColumns',  options=list(scrollX = TRUE,fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 3), lengthMenu = list(c(10, 20, -1), c('10', '20', 'All')),  pageLength = 15 ) })
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks for any helps in advance

Comment: try to remove `;` from query

Comment: I fixed the problem. all libraries must be called in both shiny.R and ui.R files. In my case I called DT only in server.R, when I added it to ui.R the problem has gone

Comment: Good, Im glad. You can place the answer yourself so the other know its covered. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just to leave here the answer if someone have the same problem.
All of libraries must be called in both shiny.R and ui.R files. In my case I called DT only in server.R, when I added it to ui.R the problem has gone